# React component not rendering after state change from callback

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a small web application to save recipes to a database and I've run into a problem where a Recipe view component uses a callback to update parent's state, but the parent is not rendering when the callback is called.

Reproduction repo: [Github](https://github.com/jonathanvd/callback-problem)

If the state is changed from within the page, everything is fine.
When the state is updated via the callback from the child component, nothing happens.

Can anyone take a look and help me please? I've been looking for 2-3 hours now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating your state instead of updating the state immutable.

You need to create a new object to save into the state instead of changing the existing one and updating this:

```
const handleChangeField = (field: string) => (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log("change field", field, "to", e.target.value)
    const tempRecipe = recipe;
    tempRecipe[field] = e.target.value; // You are changing the already saved object

    //if (field === "title") tempRecipe["name"] = recipeTitleToName(e.target.value)
    console.log("call onchange")
    onChange(tempRecipe)
  }
```

change it to:

```
const handleChangeField = (field: string) => (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log("change field", field, "to", e.target.value)
    const tempRecipe = {...recipe}; // This is now a new object and React will not skip the render
    // @ts-ignore
    tempRecipe[field] = e.target.value;

    //if (field === "title") tempRecipe["name"] = recipeTitleToName(e.target.value)
    console.log("call onchange")
    onChange(tempRecipe)
  }
```